# CK Editor doesn't send data to Firebase Database Empty

Tags: javascript, firebase

have created a Web Form to upload data(Rich Text) to Firebase Database,

But sometimes data is entered to Database and other Times the Fields in the Database is completely Empty. Can Anyone suggest me the solution as I am new to Web Dev.

Here is my WebForm Code (Rich Text is only in Description):

```js
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'quote' );
  // Initialize Firebase
  var database = firebase.database();
  var quote;

  function getdata(){
    quote = document.getElementById('quote').value;
  }
    document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(){
    getdata();
    firebase.database().ref("quoteday/quotes").set({
        Data: quote,
    })
  }
  document.getElementById('delete').onclick = function(){
      firebase.database().ref("quoteday/").remove();
  }

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
      <!----======== CSS ======== -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.17.2/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Quote day</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="quote" name="quote" rows="3"
         data-form-field="Message" placeholder="" autofocus=""
        style="display: none;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div><button id="submit">Submit/Update</button></div>
    <div><button id="delete">Delete</button></div>    
  

</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGplQ.jpg)

Comment: Please do not post the image of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your textarea is empty, you have to type **CKEDITOR.instances.quote.updateElement();** before get element value

> Updates the  element that was replaced by the editor with the     > current data available in the editor.

> Note: This method will only affect those editor instances created with the CKEDITOR.ELEMENT_MODE_REPLACE element mode or inline instances bound to
>  elements.

```
function getdata(){
CKEDITOR.instances.quote.updateElement();
quote = document.getElementById('quote').value;
}
```

If it still doesn't work, you can test this block as below

```
 firebase.database().ref("quoteday/quotes").set({
    Data: 'Test Data',
})
```

and then check your database, if Test Data saved or not ?